# Showing that (-1, 0 0) is the maximum of f(x, y, z)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

How can I show that: $(-1, 0, 0)$

is a maximum point of:

$f(x,y,z) = (7x^2 + 5y^2 + 3z^2)e^{(-x^2-y^2-z^2)} $

Comment: All three derivatives of f must vanish at (-1,0,0).  Can you show that they do?

Comment: Take $\log$ then compute the first partial derivatives, then set them to $0$.

Comment: If i if take all the partial derivatives (-1,0,0) of then doesnt that only show extrema, not maximum

Comment: compute the 3x3 Jacobian and show that it is negative definite, that will show that this is a maximum

Comment: You could also maximize $7x^2 + 5y^2 + 3z^2$ subject to $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$ for a given positive constant $r$ and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry, I couln't help giving the answer away completely since it was so clean...I deleted my answer to promote education. =)

Comment: @moreWaterplz do you mean the 1x3 Jacobian

Answer (score 1):

Take the partial derivative of f with respect to x, y, and z. Set those to zero. That will give you all the extrema. Now, you have to use the second-derivative test for multi-variable functions.

The second-derivative test requires the computation of a 3 by 3 matrix. (Because your function is a three-variable function)

D= det( $\matrix{f_{xx} & f_{xy} &f_{xz} \\
f_{yx} & f_{yy} &f_{yz}
\\
f_{zx} & f_{zy} &f_{zz}}$ )

Calculate the determinant of that and if D is positive, and $f_{xx}$ is negative, then f(a,b) is a local maximum.

If D is positive, and $f_{xx}$ is positive, then f(a,b) is a local minimum.

However, if D is negative, then that means f(a,b) is neither a maximum or a minimum. Further analysis would be required.

Comment: Is there a way i can show that its maximum without using the second derivative test?

Comment: As people mentioned in the above comments, there are other ways of finding it without invoking the second-derivative test. 
Honestly, I think the second derivative test is probably your best bet here if you can't do any of the other mentioned methods.
Is there any particular reason you don't want to use the second-derivative test?